# Getting an error when when the program tries to write to file?

Tags: java, file, debugging

The problem is the part where I write to the file. Everytime that I am done giving the values to the strings in the console, it will give me an error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java,util,Scanner,ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java,util,Scanner,findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
at java,util,Scanner,hasNextLine(Unknown Source)
at mainPackage,MainClass,main(MainClass.java:71)
```

This is my code:

```
package mainPackage;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

public class MainClass {

   private static FileWriter fw;
   private static BufferedWriter out;
   private static Scanner input;
   private static Scanner file;
   private static FileWriter fw2;
   private static BufferedWriter out2;
   private static Scanner file2;
   private static ArrayList<String> questList;
   private static ArrayList<String> ansList;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  , IllegalStateException{

      fw = new FileWriter("C:/Users/ALAN_BARE/Desktop/Dictionary.txt" , true );
      input = new Scanner(System.in);
      file = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/ALAN_BARE/Desktop/Dictionary.txt"));
      out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      fw2 = new FileWriter("C:/Users/ALAN_BARE/Desktop/Dictionary2.txt" , true);
      out2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);
      file2 = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/ALAN_BARE/Desktop/Dictionary2.txt"));
      questList = new ArrayList<String>();
      ansList = new ArrayList<String>();

      String engword;
      String gerword;
      String response;
      int counter = 0;

      //Loading the file data to the arraylist
      while (file.hasNextLine()) {
         questList.add(file.nextLine());
         ansList.add(file2.nextLine());
      }

      file.close();
      file2.close();

      System.out.println("What do you want to do, register words or Play the game?");
      response = input.nextLine();

      //Getting the values of the strings via user input
      if (response.contains("register")) {

         System.out.println("Type yor english word:");
         engword = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Type the translation in German:");
         gerword = input.nextLine();

         //writing it to a file
         if (file.hasNextLine()) {
             out.newLine();
             out.write(engword);
         }
         else {
             out.write(engword);
         }

         if (file2.hasNextLine()) {
             out2.newLine();
             out2.write(gerword);
         }
         else {
             out2.write(gerword);
         }
      }

      //The same, just for a different response
      else if (response.contains("Register")) {
         System.out.println("Type yor english word:");
         engword = input.next();
         System.out.println("Type the translation in German:");
         gerword = input.next();

         if (file.hasNextLine()) {
            out.newLine();
            out.write(engword);
         }
         else {
            out.write(engword);
         }

         if (file2.hasNextLine()) {
             out2.newLine();
             out2.write(gerword);
         }
         else {
             out2.write(gerword);
         }
      }

      out.close();
      out2.close();

      //Running the quiz game
      if (response.contains("play")) {

          while (counter <= 10 ) {
              counter++;
              int sel = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, questList.size() + 1);

              System.out.println("The english word is :" + questList.get(sel));
              System.out.println("Please type the translation in German:");
              String answer = input.nextLine();

              if (answer.contains(ansList.get(sel))) {
                  System.out.println("Correct!");
              }
              else {
                  System.out.println("Wrong! You Lose! If you want to play again, restart the app.");
                  break;
              }
          }   
      }   

      while (counter == 10) {
          System.out.println("You Win The Game! If you want to play again, restart the app.");
          counter++;
      }   
   }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Put the commas in the error to make stackoverflow not recognize it as code

Comment: Which line is 71 (where the error occurs)?

Comment: @markspace if(file.hasnextLine()){

Answer (score 2):

It is normal that you get the error after you close the `Scanner` object named as `file` at line 56

> file.close()

The error you get address the problem clearly.

> Scanner closed

Comment: This explains the error, but offers no solution which might be helpful to a future reader. Otherwise, its a succinct explanation

Comment: @BenKnoble The solution is not to use the Scanner after you've closed it. This is so trivial as to be barely worth stating.

Comment: Or to keep it closed to avoid leaving it open to do processing, and reopen it (create a new one) to write at the end. It was a suggestion; if i felt strongly i could always add my own answer

Comment: Thank you for the response, I moved the while loop that loaded up the arrayList in the game if staement and got rid of the bug.